# Debug equals() and hashCode() in Eclipse

Tags: java

I have below code and I have placed break points on overridden `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of `ContainerBean`. When I run below application in debug mode, debugger stops at `hashCode()` only for `System.out.println` line and not while trying to remove element from `List`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListRemovalDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ContainerBean> remitClaims = new ArrayList<>();

        ContainedBean addedRemit1 = new ContainedBean();
        addedRemit1.setRemitId(12345L);
        ContainerBean added1 = new ContainerBean();
        added1.setRemitBean(addedRemit1);

        remitClaims.add(added1);

        ContainedBean removedRemit1 = new ContainedBean ();
        removedRemit1.setRemitId(12345L);
        ContainerBean removed1 = new ContainerBean ();
        removed1.setRemitBean(removedRemit1);

        System.out.println("List before valid removal" + remitClaims);

        remitClaims.remove(removed1);

        System.out.println("List after valid removal" + remitClaims);



    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Would overridden `equals()` in `ContainerBean` not be called while removing element from list?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that `hashCode()` and `equals()` are working as expected i.e. elements getting removed as per `equals()` logic but its only debugger that is not taking me there on list remove function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would overridden equals() in ContainerBean not be called while
>   removing element from list ?

Yes, when **you are using `remove(Object o)`, then `equals()` in `ContainerBean` will be called to check the equality of the object and then remove it from the list** as mentioned in the `ArrayList`API below (**emphasis mine**):

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list,
>   if it is present. If the list does not contain the element, it is
>   unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the lowest index i
>   such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : **o.equals(get(i)**)) (if such an
>   element exists). Returns true if this list contained the specified
>   element (or equivalently, if this list changed as a result of the
>   call).

But, on the other side, when you are removing an element using the index of the list (i.e., using `remove(int index)`), then there will NOT be any `equals()` check.

You can look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object))

Comment: As shown in my code, I am not removing by index but passing an object to removed. Object gets removed successfully but its only Eclipse debugger not taking me there at that event.

Comment: I know that, I have just added that point to make you understand the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not give the code I have to guess: You did not override equals, but instead added an overload like this:

```
public boolean equals(ContainerBean c) { ... }
```

This will not work because equals(Object) is called.

Change your equals implementation to take an argument of type Object and it will both get called and stopped at in eclipse debugger.

Comment: I have overridden it. Taking `Object` as argument.

Comment: Then you have to show your code. `ArrayList.remove(Object)` calls `equals()` if the list is not empty and the argument is not `null`.

Comment: PS: Or maybe you have accidentally set the breakpoint on `equals()` in `ContainedBean` instead of `ContainerBean`? You should place a breakpoint on the line containing the call to `remove()` and step into that method to find out.

Comment: Stepping through is taking me there. Once I went in there through `remove` stepping, break point at equals started working. Seems like some Eclipse issue.

Answer (score 1):

Source code of ArrayList from jdk 7,

```
ArrayList.remove(Object o)
```

it invokes equals method to verify the object to remove from the collection

```
for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
   if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {
        fastRemove(index);
        return true;
   }
}
```

source: [ArrayList Source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java)